# Image not updating when image file is deleted and replaced in Java

Tags: java, image

I am copying an Image file to a location then, I load the image using the following code:

`Image image=new ImageIcon("C:/test/pics/pic1.png").getImage();`

Then I print it out on to a window.
I then delete the Image.
I do this for 10 images and everything works fine.
However, when the program loops back to the first image, it doesn't update it and displays the old image. I also made sure that the image files were getting deleted.

Comment: "I print it out on to a window." - need more details than this if you want a competent answer

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [mcve]. There is not enough information in your question for us to be able to help you. Thanks!

Comment: Problem suggests that you're reusing the same filenames. Is this true?

Comment: @AndrewMairose I override the paint method in JFrame then I use the drawImage method.

Answer (score 1):

Do an:

```
image.getImage().flush();
```

to clear the cache.